# Is there a way to let selenium ignore the timeoutexception Error and continue if it happens?

Tags: python, selenium

I am using selenium with python and my chromedriver and chrome.exe is ver90.0

I am having a problem that the script will stop once a timeout error occurs and the problem is that it always happens, sometimes in a few hours, sometimes in a few minutes.

It will show up something like :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.timeoutexception: message: timeout: timed out receiving message from renderer: -0.014
```

when this happens, I see the webpage is usually loading and it basically can't load resulting the error occuring.

Is there a way to ignore this error and basically let the script either refresh or just continue loading to the next webpage in the list. An example code will be like this:

```
while True:
     driver.get(thislist[i])
     if .......:
        i = i + 1
```

I tried many fixes, but none of them work. I tried with beta chrome.exe and chrome webdriver ver 91.0. I also tried including chrome_options and I also tried some headers that's not in this code, but I always eneded up receiving the timeout error. I asked this question a few times before, but there hasn't bveen a fix that works.

```
chrome_options.add_argument('--enable-automation')
chrome_options.add_argument('--lang=en')

chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")
chrome_options.headless = True


chrome_options.add_experimental_option ("debuggerAddress", "localhost:8989")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Webdriver/chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
while True:
    try:
        driver.get(thislist[i])
    except timeoutexception as e:
        print(e)
        continue
    else:
        # do what you want here
```

When there is a timeoutexception, the code will just print it and continue to the next loop. If there is no one, then you can do web driving under "else:".

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

What about adding a `try catch` around your operation that raises the error. If  there is an error, you simply `continue` in your loop.

Use `Exception` since your don't know the kind of exception that will be thrown.

---

You can always set the timeout for selenium to be longer with the following line: `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`